# iPhone https authorization using client certificates

Tags: iphone, https, http-live-streaming, mpmovieplayer, client-certificates

I am interested in playing HTTP live streaming data from my app. The stream (which I create) is encrypted, and a URL pointing to the AES key is included in the stream index file.
MPMoviePlayer hits this URL for the AES key, when it sees that encryption is enabled.

I would like this URL to be served by https, and for MMMoviePlayer to use a client certificate that I provide when the user purchases the content. I also do not want any user interaction for authentication, since they have already agreed to purchase the certificate.

Can I programmatically install the client certificate from my app so that MMMoviePlayer transparently uses this certificate to authenticate when getting the AES key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, check out the CredentialImportController class in this sample code http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009558

you will store the information in the application keychain which is not accessible by any other application unless you share that keychain using your app id.

Comment: Are you saying it is possible for the MPMoviePlayer to use a certificate from keychain? How?